# How to index an $or query with sort

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a query that looks something like this:

```
db.things.find({
  deleted: false,
  type: 'thing',
  $or: [{
    'creator._id': someid
  }, {
    'parent._id': someid
  }, {
    'somerelation._id': someid
  }]
}).sort({
  'date.created': -1
})
```

That is, I want to find documents that meets one of those three conditions and sort it by newest. However, $or queries do not use indexes in parallel when used with a sort. Thus, how would I index this query?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-behaviors-and-limitations

You can assume the following selectivity:

- `deleted` - 99%
- `type` - 25%
- `creator._id`, `parent._id`, `somerelation._id` - < 1%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you are going to need more than one index for this query; there is no doubt about that.

The question is *what indexes*?

Now you have to take into consideration that none of your `$or`s will be able to sort their data cardinally in an optimal manner using the index due to a bug in MongoDBs query optimizer: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205 .

So you know that the `$or` will have some performance problems with a sort and that putting the sort field into the `$or` clause indexes is useless atm.

So considering this the first index you want is one that covers the base query you are making. As @Leonid said you could make this into a compound index, however, I would not do it the order he has done it. Instead, I would do:

```
db.col.ensureIndex({type:-1,deleted:-1,date.created:-1})
```

I am very unsure about the `deleted` field being in the index at all due to its super low selectivity; it could, in fact, create a less performant operation (this is true for most databases including SQL) being in the index rather than being taken out. This part will need testing by you; maybe the field should be last (?).

As to the order of the index, again I have just guessed. I have said DESC for all fields because your sort is DESC, but you will need to `explain` this yourself here.

So that should be able to handle the master clause of your query. Now to deal with those `$or`s.

Each `$or` will use an index separately, and the MongoDB query optimizer will look for indexes for them separately too as though they are separate queries altogether, so something worth noting here is a little snag about compound indexes ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes ) is that they work upon prefixes ( an example note here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#id5 ) so you can't make one single compound index to cover all three clauses, so a more optimal method of declaring indexes on the `$or` (considering the bug above) is:

```
db.col.ensureindex({creator._id:1});
db.col.ensureindex({aprent._id:1});
db.col.ensureindex({somrelation._id:1});
```

It should be able to get you started on making optimal indexes for your query.

I should stress however that you need to test this yourself.

Comment: +1 just for the link to the bug. if they're going to fix this in the future then i can just hack around it for now by making separate queries.

Comment: going to mark this as the answer because of the link to the bug report

Answer (score 3):

<s>Mongodb can use only one index per query, so</s> I can't see the way to use indexes to query `someid` in your model.

So, the best approach is to add special field for this task:

```
ids = [creator._id, parent._id, somerelation._id]
```

In this case you'll be able to query without using `$or` operator:

```
db.things.find({
  deleted: false,
  type: 'thing',
  ids: someid
}).sort({
  'date.created': -1
})
```

In this case your index will look something like this:

```
{deleted:1, type:1, ids:1, 'date.created': -1}
```

Comment: $or can and will use a index per clause so you statement about single indexes is not true in this case

Comment: Yes, you're right, my fault. But `sort` complicates it all anyway. I'm not sure that data can be effectively sorted using three different indexes.

Comment: I ran some tests with `explain()`. MongoDB uses only one index when `sort` is present.

Comment: Weird I get same results from explain, though not from a performance

Comment: ideally yes, but there are multiple problems. first is that these IDs are queried differently, so I would end up with multiple combinations of `ids`. Secondly, the number of IDs in total could be pretty large, making it too large for a single index.

Answer (score 1):

If you had flexibility to adjust the schema, I would suggest adding a new field, associatedIds : [ ] which would hold creator._id, parent._id, some relation._id - you can update that field atomically when you update the main corresponding field, but now you can have a compound index on this field, type and created_date which eliminates the need for $or in your query entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your requirement for indexing  , I would suggest you to use $orderBy operator along side your $or query. By that I mean you should be able to index on the criteria's in your $or expressions used in your $or query and then you can $orderBy to sort the result.

For example:

```
db.things.find({
         deleted: false,
         type: 'thing',
         $or: [{
               'creator._id': someid
              }, {
          'parent._id': someid
          }, {
          'somerelation._id': someid
          }]
        },{$orderBy:{'date.created': -1}})
```

The above query would require compound indexes on each of the fields in the $or expressions combined with the sort object specified in the orderBy criteria.

for example:

```
db.things.ensureIndex{'parent._id': 1,"date.created":-1}
and so on for other fields.
```

It is a good practice to specify "limit" for the result to prevent mongodb from performing a huge in memory sort.
Read More on [$orderBy operator here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/orderby/)